# Drawing characters to form at timer tick

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to draw a character on the screen every 500 milliseconds but they won't appear on the screen

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class Form4 : Form
{
    public Form4()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    PictureBox pb;
    Bitmap surface;
    Graphics device;
    Timer timer;
    int num = 0;
    string text = "This is a test";
    char[] textChar;
    Font font = new Font("Black Ops One", 20, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

    private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //picture box
        pb = new PictureBox();
        pb.Parent = this;
        pb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        pb.BackColor = Color.Black;
        //create graphics device
        surface = new Bitmap(this.Size.Width, this.Size.Height);
        pb.Image = surface;
        device = Graphics.FromImage(surface);
        //set up timer
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 500;
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Tick += new System.EventHandler(TimerTick);
        //mis
        textChar = text.ToCharArray();
    }

    public void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DrawText();
        if (num > textChar.Length - 1) 
        {
           timer.Enabled = false;
           MessageBox.Show("have hit the end");
        }
    } 

    public void DrawText()
    {
        device.DrawString(textChar[num].ToString(), font, Brushes.Red, 10, 10 + num * 22)
        num++;
    }
}
```

I hope to have the form at the end have the string on the form, but have the characters come up one by one. The form won't show any of the text. It only shows a black background.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the tick event handler, see if it is even being hit.  If it is and it is writing to the screen, add a screen refresh command (this.refresh() or similar, google for correct syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the bitmap the image of the picture box `pb.Image = surface`.

```
public void DrawText()
    {
        device.DrawString(textChar[num].ToString(), font, Brushes.Red, 10, 10 + num * 22)
        num++;
        pb.Image = surface;
    }
```

Comment: Instead of re-assigning the Image, you could also just tell the PictureBox to repaint itself with: `pb.Invalidate();`